# Troubleshooting VAT calculation issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

The first item scanned is coming correct, but the items scanned after are not calculating VAT. I attempted to implement the necessary adjustments, but unfortunately, my efforts failed. I'm still determining the specific areas that need changes to achieve the desired outcome. Additionally, I encountered difficulties while installing the debug bar, which further complicated the troubleshooting process. Despite my best efforts, I remain unable to resolve the issue. Any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
public function getProductsByBarcode()
{
    if (request()->ajax()) {
        $output = [];
        try {
            $location_id = request()->input('location_id', null);
            $check_qty = request()->input('check_qty', false);
            $business_id = request()->session()->get('user.business_id');
            $product_types = request()->get('product_types', []);
            $price_group_id = request()->input('price_group', null);
            $sku = request()->get('sku');
            if(empty($sku)){
                $sku = request()->input('sku');
            }

            $query = Product::join('variations', 'products.id', '=', 'variations.product_id')
                        ->active()
                        ->whereNull('variations.deleted_at')
                        ->leftjoin('units as U', 'products.unit_id', '=', 'U.id')
                        ->leftjoin(
                            'variation_location_details AS VLD',
                            function ($join) use ($location_id) {
                                $join->on('variations.id', '=', 'VLD.variation_id');
                                if (! empty($location_id)) {
                                    $join->where(function ($query) use ($location_id) {
                                        $query->where('VLD.location_id', '=', $location_id);
                                        $query->orWhereNull('VLD.location_id');
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        );

            if (! empty($price_group_id)) {
                $query->leftjoin(
                    'variation_group_prices AS VGP',
                    function ($join) use ($price_group_id) {
                        $join->on('variations.id', '=', 'VGP.variation_id')
                            ->where('VGP.price_group_id', '=', $price_group_id);
                    }
                );
            }

            $query->where('products.business_id', $business_id)
                  ->where('products.type', '!=', 'modifier');

            if (! empty($product_types)) {
                $query->whereIn('products.type', $product_types);
            }

            $query->where('products.business_id', $business_id)
                  ->where('products.type', '!=', 'modifier')
                  ->where('products.sku', '=', $sku);

            if ($check_qty) {
                $query->where('VLD.qty_available', '>', 0);
            }

            if (!empty($location_id)) {
                $query->ForLocation($location_id);
            }

            $query->select(
                    'products.id as product_id',
                    'products.name',
                    'products.type',
                    'products.enable_stock',
                    'variations.id as variation_id',
                    'variations.name as variation',
                    'VLD.qty_available',
                    'variations.sell_price_inc_tax as selling_price',
                    'variations.sub_sku',
                    'U.short_name as unit'
                );

            $query->groupBy('variations.id');

            $product = $query->orderBy('VLD.qty_available', 'desc')->first();

            if(empty($product)){
                $output['success'] = false;
                $output['msg'] = __('lang_v1.no_products_found');
                return $output;
            } else {
                $is_overselling_allowed = request()->get('is_overselling_allowed');
                $for_so = request()->get('for_so');
                $is_draft = request()->get('is_draft');
                $enable_stock = $product->enable_stock;
                $qty_available = $product->qty_available;
                $variation_id = $product->variation_id;

                if ($enable_stock != 1 || $qty_available > 0 || $is_overselling_allowed || $for_so || $is_draft) {
                    $row_count = request()->get('product_row');
                    $row_count = $row_count + 1;
                    $quantity = request()->get('quantity', 1);
                    $is_direct_sell = false;
                    $output = $this->getSellLineRowForBarcode($variation_id, $location_id, $quantity, $row_count, $is_direct_sell);
                } else {
                    $output['success'] = false;
                    $output['msg'] = __('lang_v1.item_out_of_stock');
                    return $output;
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::emergency('File:'.$e->getFile().'Line:'.$e->getLine().'Message:'.$e->getMessage());
            $output['success'] = false;
            $output['msg'] = __('lang_v1.item_out_of_stock');
        }
        return $output;
    }
}

private function getSellLineRowForBarcode($variation_id, $location_id, $quantity, $row_count, $is_direct_sell, $so_line = null)
{
    // omitted for brevity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the below function and let me know the results:

```
private function getSellLineRowForBarcode($variation_id, $location_id, $quantity, $row_count, $is_direct_sell, $so_line = null)
{

 $business_id = request()->session()->get('user.business_id');

$business_details = $this->businessUtil->getDetails($business_id);
$pos_settings = empty($business_details->pos_settings) ? $this->businessUtil->defaultPosSettings() : json_decode($business_details->pos_settings, true);

$check_qty = !empty($pos_settings['allow_overselling']) ? false : true;


$is_sales_order = request()->has('is_sales_order') && request()->input('is_sales_order') == 'true' ? true : false;
$is_draft = request()->has('is_draft') && request()->input('is_draft') == 'true' ? true : false;

if ($is_sales_order || !empty($so_line) || $is_draft) {
    $check_qty = false;
}


if (request()->input('disable_qty_alert') === 'true') {
    $pos_settings['allow_overselling'] = true;
}


$product = $this->productUtil->getDetailsFromVariation($variation_id, $business_id, $location_id, $check_qty);


if (!isset($product->quantity_ordered)) {
    $product->quantity_ordered = $quantity;
}


$product->secondary_unit_quantity = !isset($product->secondary_unit_quantity) ? 0 : $product->secondary_unit_quantity;


$product->formatted_qty_available = $this->productUtil->num_f($product->qty_available, false, null, true);


$sub_units = $this->productUtil->getSubUnits($business_id, $product->unit_id, false, $product->product_id);


$customer_id = request()->get('customer_id', null);
$cg = $this->contactUtil->getCustomerGroup($business_id, $customer_id);
$percent = (empty($cg) || empty($cg->amount) || $cg->price_calculation_type != 'percentage') ? 0 : $cg->amount;
$product->default_sell_price = $product->default_sell_price + ($percent * $product->default_sell_price / 100);
$product->sell_price_inc_tax = $product->sell_price_inc_tax + ($percent * $product->sell_price_inc_tax / 100);


$tax_dropdown = TaxRate::forBusinessDropdown($business_id, true, true);


$lot_numbers = [];
if (request()->session()->get('business.enable_lot_number') == 1 || request()->session()->get('business.enable_product_expiry') == 1) {
    $lot_number_obj = $this->transactionUtil->getLotNumbersFromVariation($variation_id, $business_id, $location_id, true);
    foreach ($lot_number_obj as $lot_number) {
        $lot_number->qty_formated = $this->productUtil->num_f($lot_number->qty_available);
        $lot_numbers[] = $lot_number;
    }
}
$product->lot_numbers = $lot_numbers;

$price_group = request()->input('price_group');
if (!empty($price_group) && $price_group != "NaN") {
    $variation_group_prices = $this->productUtil->getVariationGroupPrice($variation_id, $price_group, $product->tax_id);
    if (!empty($variation_group_prices['price_inc_tax'])) {
        $product->sell_price_inc_tax = $variation_group_prices['price_inc_tax'];
        $product->default_sell_price = $variation_group_prices['price_exc_tax'];
    }
}


$warranties = $this->__getwarranties();


$output = [
    'variation_id' => $variation_id,
    'success' => true,
    'enable_sr_no' => $product->enable_sr_no
];


if (request()->get('type') == 'sell-return') {
    $output['html_content'] = view('sell_return.partials.product_row')->with(compact('product', 'row_count', 'tax_dropdown', 'enabled_modules', 'sub_units'))->render();
} else {
    $is_cg = !empty($cg->id) ? true : false;
    $discount = $this->productUtil->getProductDiscount($product, $business_id, $location_id, $is_cg, $price_group, $variation_id);
    $edit_discount = auth()->user()->can('edit_product_discount_from_pos_screen');
    $edit_price = auth()->user()->can('edit_product_price_from_pos_screen');

    $output['html_content'] = view('sale_pos.product_row')
        ->with(compact('product', 'row_count', 'tax_dropdown', 'enabled_modules', 'pos_settings', 'sub_units', 'discount', 'waiters', 'edit_discount', 'edit_price', 'purchase_line_id', 'warranties', 'quantity', 'is_direct_sell', 'so_line', 'is_sales_order', 'last_sell_line'))
        ->render();
}

return $output;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78195725/edit) and explain what you changed. There was a lot of code posted, and both the question and this answer have different formatting, so it's really difficult to tell what you changed and why you think it would fix their issue.

Comment: I changed the code and now it is showing product out of stock even though we are not using stock manage

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).